# How to highlight specific keywords in a Qt text editor application

Tags: c++, qt

I have built a simple text editor app in Qt and i would like it to highlight/bold certain keywords. I have the following highlight function that is called every time a letter is typed, and when the file is opened:

```
void objectDetector::highlightKeywords()
{

 QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

// keywords
QStringList keywords;
keywords << "red" << "bold";  

// Define text formats for highlighting
QTextCharFormat keywordFormat;
keywordFormat.setForeground(Qt::red);
keywordFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);

// Iterate over keywords and apply formatting
for (const QString& keyword : keywords) {
    QTextDocument* document = ui->textEdit->document();
    QTextCursor cursor(document);

    while (!cursor.isNull() && !cursor.atEnd()) {
        cursor = document->find(keyword, cursor, QTextDocument::FindWholeWords);

        if (!cursor.isNull()) {
            cursor.mergeCharFormat(keywordFormat);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Whenever a key word is found, the program crashes however. When run in the debug mode, it says a seg fault has occurred.

EDIT: The issue may be around the cursor.mergeCharFormat(keywordFormat) as I added a cout line after it which never gets called, but the lines before it in the loop get called several times repeatedly, perhaps explaining the seg fault?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setExtraSelections as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is to use a `QSyntaxHighlighter`, such as:

```cpp
class MySyntaxHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter {
public:
    MySyntaxHighlighter(QObject* parent) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
    {
        KeywordsRed.push_back (
            QRegularExpression(
                "\\bred\\b",
                QRegularExpression::PatternOption::CaseInsensitiveOption
            )
        );
        KeywordsBold.push_back(
            QRegularExpression(
                "\\bbold\\b",
                QRegularExpression::PatternOption::CaseInsensitiveOption
            )
        );
    }
    virtual void highlightBlock(const QString& text) override
    {
        QTextCharFormat redFormat, boldFormat;
        redFormat.setForeground(QBrush(QColor::fromRgb(200, 0, 0)));
        if (auto textEdit = dynamic_cast<QTextEdit*>(parent()); textEdit) {
            QFont font = textEdit->font(); font.setBold(true);
            boldFormat.setFont(font);
        }
        for (const QRegularExpression& regexp : std::as_const(KeywordsRed)) {
            QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = regexp.globalMatch(text);
            while (matchIterator.hasNext()) {
                QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
                setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), redFormat);
            }
        }
        for (const QRegularExpression& regexp : std::as_const(KeywordsBold)) {
            QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = regexp.globalMatch(text);
            while (matchIterator.hasNext()) {
                QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
                setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), boldFormat);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<QRegularExpression> KeywordsRed, KeywordsBold;
};
```

The highlighter is attached by simply creating it on a `QTextEdit`:

```cpp
auto highlighter = new (std::nothrow) MySyntaxHighlighter(edit);
```

Comment: Tried this and itworked for me! The comment under my question post also worked, and is what I ended up going with because it required less modification of my original code.

Comment: Is it code you want to keep though?